# converting int to float in np.array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

First question ever:D

I am trying to create an np.ndarray as follows:

```
n = 100000
f = np.ndarray(n, dtype=float)
k = n/5
obs = np.ndarray(k, dtype=float)
intervals = np.empty((2,k/2))
```

I get the following error for the last two arrays:
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: use `k  = n // 5 `

Comment: Thanks alot, this works if I do this as well
intervals = np.empty((2,k//2))

Answer (score -1):

Convert n and k variable using float function. Float error is showing because np.ndarray is reading data as a integer where you have given data type as float.

Comment: That is incorrect. The error is that `k` is provided as an argument to `np.ndarray`, which requires an `int`, but `k` is a float.